# How to use RSPEC to test API request that contains signature?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rspec

I have a rails app that uses [Yelp API for ruby](https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-ruby). It makes a request to Yelp and returns rails object based on location. Basic premises:

On config/initializers/yelp.rb, it has my credentials.

```
Yelp.client.configure do |config|
  config.consumer_key = ENV["consumer_key"]
  config.consumer_secret = ENV["consumer_secret"]
  config.token = ENV["token"]
  config.token_secret = ENV["token_secret"]
end
```

On posts_controller.rb, I do the search under `results` variable.

```
def scrape
    results = Yelp.client.search('SOMECITY', {limit: 1})

    results.businesses.each do |result|
      #generate new post instance
      @post = Post.new
      @post.phone = result.phone
      @post.name = result.name
      @post.rating = result.rating
      ...
      #save post information
      @post.save

    end
    redirect_to :posts
  end
```

The code works. I am going backwards to do the testing after the code runs because I am still learning how RSpec works. I am having problem testing the request to Yelp API on my posts_controller_spec.rb I was trying to figure out how to test the redirect. Somehow RSpec does not recognize my signature.

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe PostsController do
  describe "POST scrape" do
    it "creates new restaurant attributes from yelp"
    it "saves new restaurant attributes from yelp`"

    it "redirect to Posts index" do
      results = Yelp.client.search('moreno valley', {limit: 1, category_filter: "donuts"})
      post :scrape
      response.should redirect_to(action: 'index')
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the error that I got:

```
Failures:

  1) PostsController POST scrape redirect to Posts index
     Failure/Error: results = Yelp.client.search('SOMECITY', {limit: 1})

     Yelp::Error::InvalidSignature:
       Signature was invalid
```

I am using `* yelp (2.1.4)`

What is the proper way to test API request using RSpec so my testing can pass?

Comment: Can you post your Yelp gem version?

Comment: version 2.1.4. Updated my post to include the info too. Thanks!!

Comment: I've setup a test app with the Yelp gem and copied your code for testing. It works OK for me when running RSpec as well as through Puma locally. [Docs here](https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/errors) say that it indicates the oauth_signature for the request was invalid. But it is difficult to troubleshoot when I cannot reproduce it. Would you be willing to share the code so I can try to help?